# ¿Cómo verificar correctamente si un togglebutton está actualmente seleccionado en la consola de Chrome usando los comandos de jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, consola, google-chrome, google-developers-console

[Hay una página](https://www.investing.com/economic-calendar/) que muestra el calendario económico para `Hoy` por defecto, que aparece en la imagen siguiente.

[image]

He estado intentando encontrar un comando `jQuery` que retorne `true` o `false` dependiendo de sí el toggleButton llamado `Today` está actualmente seleccionado, pero no he podido dar con algo.

El código de dicho enlace aparece aquí:

```
<div class="float_lang_base_1 js-tabs-economic">
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="timeFrame_yesterday" data-identifier="" class="newBtn toggleButton LightGray first">Yesterday</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="timeFrame_today" data-identifier="" class="newBtn toggleButton LightGray toggled">Today</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="timeFrame_tomorrow" data-identifier="" class="newBtn toggleButton LightGray">Tomorrow</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="timeFrame_thisWeek" data-identifier="" class="newBtn toggleButton LightGray">This Week</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="timeFrame_nextWeek" data-identifier="" class="newBtn toggleButton LightGray">Next Week</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="datePickerToggleBtn" data-identifier="" class="newBtn toggleButton LightGray datePickerBtn noText datePickerIconWrap">&nbsp;&nbsp;</a>
</div>
```

Intenté el siguiente método en la `Chrome Console`:

```
$('#timeFrame_today').is(':selected')
```

Y este retornó:

> false

Lo cual no debería ser el caso pues como lo mencioné, el botón `#timeFrame_today` (también conocido como `Today`) se encuentra seleccionado por defecto, entonces estoy perdido aquí.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según veo, usan una clase denominada `toggled` para indicarlo, así que lo más practico será ver si la tiene mediante el método [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) de jquery

```
$('#timeFrame_today').hasClass('toggled')
```

lo cual devuelve:

```
true
```

Comment: ¡Oh así que era eso! Tiene mucho sentido ahora, ¡muchas gracias!